# SQL Text Function for special characters

Tags: sql, text, count, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a field with text reviews in it and I want to spot where people have used special characters to get offensive words etc past the filters, so instead of typing `badword` they type `b.a.d.w.o.r.d` or `b*a*d*w*o*r*d`,

Is there a way to look for say 3 or more special characters in word in a text review, maybe some sort of count function for special characters?

Comment: do you have a table/field with words you dont allow?

Comment: Everything is possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a table with a field containing words you dont want to allow you could add it in your `WHERE` clause like so using `REGEX_REPLACE`.

```
SELECT yourfield
FROM yourtable
WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE(yourfield,'[^a-zA-Z'']','') NOT IN (SELECT badwords 
                                                         FROM badwordstable)
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, you wouldn't believe how creative some people are in getting stuff past the filters !